# How to GET the current profile via pactl?

Tags: pulseaudio

There are examples out there of how to set the card profile via `pacmd` or `pactl` (with a simple `set-card-profile`). But is there any analog where i can check the currently set profile?

`get-card-profile` does not work and generates an error, i was hoping that even though it wasn't documented it would be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have found the answer myself. It is somehow hidden within `pacmd list-cards` output. It has the section `profiles:`.

I do not know if it also outputs it somewhere all by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `pactl list cards` and see the currently selected profile under `Active Profile`.

Of course, you can filter the output to only show the profile information; for example, if you want to see only the currently selected profile for your bluetooth card, you can use something like

```bash
$ pactl list cards | awk -v RS='' '/bluez/' | awk -F': ' '/Active Profile/ { print $2 }'
```